# What can we say about the probability of points satisfying an inequality

Tags: probability, optimization, convex-analysis

Consider

1- $\lambda_1<0<\lambda_2<\ldots<\lambda_n$ are some real scalars.

2- $x_i$'s are real variables satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=1$

what can we say about the probability of points $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the following equation:

$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2x_i^2-(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i^2)^2\geq-\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_n}{2}$

can we say that the probability of points satisfying this inequality increases by growing $n$? why? can we compute or approximate this probability?

Comment: What exactly is random about this?  If everything is fixed, then the probability of satisfying the stated equation is either 0 or 1.

Comment: If a point in n dimensional space satisfying relation (2)- a point on hyper sphere- is selected randomly with what probability the mentioned above inequality holds? does this probability increase by growing n?